# Identical ApplyFilter code works on report load but fails on form button press

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm working on a form that filters the query data based on date-of-birth. Should be simple. At first I was going to do it as a report, but decided a form would be better. On the report, my filter code works fine; it checks values from unbound boxes on a selection form and filters accordingly. Like so:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

Dim start_dob As String
Dim end_dob As String

If CurrentProject.AllForms("frm_Birth_range_selector").IsLoaded = True Then
    start_dob = Forms!frm_Birth_range_selector!txt_DOB_start
    end_dob = Forms!frm_Birth_range_selector!txt_DOB_end
    Me.FilterOn = True
    DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "DOB >= '" & start_dob & "' and DOB <= '" & end_dob & "'"
End If

End Sub
```

I tried to do the same thing on a form, using unbound boxes on itself and a button to apply the filter. Same query. Same code except referencing different boxes. Same box properties, I even tried copy-pasting boxes from the selector form to make sure I didn't miss something. This code returns a run-time 3464 error, `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` error:

```
Private Sub Command33_Click()

Dim start_dob As String
Dim end_dob As String

start_dob = Me.txt_DOB_start
end_dob = Me.txt_DOB_end
Me.FilterOn = True
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "DOB >= '" & start_dob & "' and DOB <= '" & end_dob & "'"

End Sub
```

I tried replacing `Me.` with `Forms!frm_birth_log!`. No change.

Comment: Dates are encapsulated using #. I.e. dob >= #27/03/1991#

Comment: I'm amazed it works - as you are comparing strings, not dates.

Comment: What is the `format` of report textboxes vs form textboxes? Is either formatted as *Short Date* or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may be related to the date - if day is > 12, your code may work incorrectly because date should be in American format. Use something like this:

```
Private Sub Command33_Click()
    Dim start_dob As Date
    Dim end_dob As Date

    If IsDate(Me.txt_DOB_start) And IsDate(Me.txt_DOB_end) Then
        start_dob = CDate(Me.txt_DOB_start)
        end_dob = CDate(Me.txt_DOB_end)
        Me.Filter = "DOB >= #" & Format(start_dob, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "# and DOB <= #" & Format(end_dob, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"
        Me.FilterOn = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid date"
    End If
End Sub
```

And I would recommend always use `Option Explicit` directive in each module. With this directive compiler would give you an error because you declared `send_dob` and used `end_dob`. Such kind errors sometimes lead to unpredictable results and hard to find.